# Four eyes have I, and a mouth of one

Tags: riddle

Four eyes have I
And a mouth of one
I do not speak
For I have no tongue
I have the curves
To match my eyes
I'm wide and skinny
To no one's surprise
I may be a female
Given my start
St. Louis holds
The bottom of my heart
Two legs I have
Though I cannot stand
But I think they're the finest
In all the lands
Can you hazard a guess
As to what, or who
Surely by now
I've given you plenty of clues

**What or who am I?**

Comment: Was not aware, so thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go with

> The **Mississippi (River)**

Explanation will follow, gradually.

Four eyes have I and a mouth of one

> M**i**ss**i**ss**i**pp**i** are the four I's, and the river has one mouth.  **OP Edit: Additionally, the "M" can appear to be "mouth-like".**

I do not speak for I have no tongue

> Rivers have mouths but no tongues.

I have the curves to match my eyes, I'm wide and skinny to no one's surprise

> Rivers have curves and have different sizes at different points.  **OP Reasoning: The curves to match the eyes (i's), is the four s's in Mississippi.**

I may be a female given my start

> This is where I'm confused, at least a little bit. Maybe it's that rivers and bodies of water can be referred to as "she," but I'm not sure. **OP Reasoning: The first 4 letters "Miss" indicates a female.**

St. Louis holds the bottom of my heart

> The river begins in St. Louis, or at least around that area.

Two legs I have, though I cannot stand

> The "legs" of a river are not really for standing. **OP Reasoning: The "legs" are the p's in Mississippi.**

But I think they're the finest in all the lands

> The Mississippi river is the longest in the United States.

Comment: Correct answer, and interesting take on the explanation - not quite how I imagined it to be. I'll edit the post with a full explanation (spoiler-tagged, of course).

Comment: I thought river when I read the title.

Comment: I may be a female given my start: Mississipi starts with "Miss"

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

> The Mississippi river

Why?

> It is wide and skinny.  St. Louis holds the bottom of its heart.  A river has one mouth.  Cannot stand because legs of a river are not used for standing.

Comment: looks like I was a minute or so too late.  I should of posted the answer first and explanation later, lol.

Comment: Right answer, though someone beat you to the punch!

Answer (score 1):

My guess

> Eyeglasses

Four eyes have I And a mouth of one

> Four eyes is for someone with eyeglasses, also have one mouth

I'm wide and skinny To no one's surprise I may be a female

> The lens is wide and skinny

St. Louis holds The bottom of my heart

> St Louis is one of eyeglass brand company.

Two legs I have
Though I cannot stand
But I think they're the finest
In all the lands

> Eyeglasses have two handle and fit in everyone head.

Comment: Good answer, but doesn't fit all the criteria. Good job with the explanation on this, too - I'd have never thought of it!